# docker-compose up with volumes - "no such file or directory" for package.json

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose

I have a Dockerfile and a docker-compose.yml file. Everything works fine until I add the volumes lines to the docker-compose file. When I do add the volumes I get the below error. I am using docker toolbox with Oracle VM VirtualBox on windows 7.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:10.16.3

WORKDIR /usr/src/facerecognitionbrain-api

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm install

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
 facerecognitionbrain-api:
  container_name: backend
  # image: node:10.16.3
  build: ./
  command: npm start
  working_dir: /usr/src/facerecognitionbrain-api
  ports:
  - "3008:3008"
  volumes:
  - ./:/usr/src/facerecognitionbrain-api
```

**Error**

```
backend                     | npm ERR! code ENOENT
backend                     | npm ERR! errno -2
backend                     | npm ERR! syscall open
backend                     | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/facerecognitionbrain-api/package.json'
backend                     | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
backend                     | npm ERR! enoent
backend                     |
backend                     | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
backend                     | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-10-18T10_24_08_071Z-debug.log
backend exited with code 254
```

Comment: Note you are doing this double now (copy and share volume) but that should still work. Can you share the contents of the log mentioned, and also place an "ls" command just before the command that fails? Is the package.json available in the container? The error is the current working directory the NPM command is executed in does not have a package.json. In case you run on windows, did you enable shared drives in the Docker for Windows settings? (for volumes to work).

Comment: @bastijn I am very new to this. How do I access that log? And also how do I place an ls command before the command that fails?

Comment: @bastijn alos this is windows 7 so it doesn't have Docker for Windows settings i don't think?

Comment: It does I assume, never checked personally. If you go to the settings of your Docker for Windows (right-click the whale) there should be a section [shared drives] or something similar. Check the boxes to you drives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should volume only a sub/directory of your WORKDIR, not the full /usr/src/facerecognitionbrain-api.

Here the volume is created, and then npm tries to read package.json, but docker looks for the file in your volume, which is empty.

Comment: perfect! that worked. So why is the volume empty? Doesn't the volumes command put everything from the host root into the path I specify? Also in this case does the COPY command in the Dockerfile not get run?

Comment: I think docker is expecting you to create document in the volume after you set it, so it is created empty and override the existing folder (or docker just ignore them).
You should see it as a longterm storage for your file in the docker.

Comment: docker-compose doesn't seem to be getting the updates when i make changes now. could this be a side effect of this fix?